# can some one explain to me the horrible model performance I'm seeing in a text classifier?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, model-fitting

I'm fitting data to a simple model for a text classifier NLP project I'm working on.
My results are, in a word, bad:
***loss: -268148.5000*** - accuracy: 0.0762 - ***val_loss: -933167.1250*** - val_accuracy: 0.0784

What could be the cause of the loss & val_loss values being so high?!

My model, just in case it helps, is this:

```
#basic model
model = Sequential()

model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_length=max_length))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1,activation="sigmoid"))
model.summary()

#basic model compile & run
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Update: the tokenizing:

```
vocab_size = 10000
embedding_dim = 50
max_length = 100
padding_type='post'
trunc_type='post'
oov_tok = "<OOV>"


tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = vocab_size, oov_token=oov_tok)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(lyrics_train)

word_index = tokenizer.word_index
print(len(word_index))
print(word_index)


lyrics_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(lyrics_train)
lyrics_train_final = pad_sequences(lyrics_train,maxlen=max_length, padding=padding_type, 
                       truncating=trunc_type)

lyrics_test = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(lyrics_test)
lyrics_test_final = pad_sequences(lyrics_test,maxlen=max_length, 
                               padding=padding_type, truncating=trunc_type)
```

Comment: what data are you training on? what embeddings are used? also, how did you decide to use such interesting architecture? I think this architecture is not very good.

Comment: What are your labels, are you sure it is binary classification?

Comment: @Dr. Snoopy I'm not sure what the labels you're reffering to are. I've updated the question with the tokenizatoin code of the data set I have. One colum is lyrics to songs, the other column is the genre of music the song is from. I'm trying to build a classifier to predict the genre from the lyrics.

Comment: @Danil Konoyhin - I know its not the best, I'm trying to learn how to create these predictors. The embeddings are the standard tensorflow tokenizer with a diemension of 50

Comment: Labels are the y values you are using for training, is it binary classification or not? How many classes are there?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy - ahh sorry, there are 10 genres which I have factorized from strings. I'm trying to predict which of those a particular lyrics belongs to. If I understood you correctly

Comment: Then why are you using a sigmoid activation with one neuron at the output, and binary crossentropy loss? You are not doing binary classification (10 classes).

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy oh.my.god - I was so fixated that I was after screwing up the data in the wrangling I just used the default model given in the examples. I never thought to look at what it was doing.  OK thanks for that, I'm away to read up on the correct activations and validations.